# What kind of gun did Robocop use in the first movie?

Tags: props, robocop

What kind of gun did Robocop use in the first movie? I know it was a triple burst handgun with a single shot capability.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's that obsession with GIFs? Why does every single image here have to move? That's really distracting and doesn't help identifying the gun the slightest.

Comment: A picture maybe. You had pictures. But sometimes *one* picture says more than 50, or 500 in fast succession that you can neither pause nor make much sense of. The point is that they don't really add anything. We *know* this is about Robocop's gun, an image of that is enough to clarify that. Showing about 12 scenes of him swirling it around doesn't really improve upon that clarification further. Yes, pictures can help, but class over mass is the key here.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Beretta 93R (as the "Auto 9")**

The primary weapon that Robocop uses in the original 1987 film is the [Beretta 93R](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/RoboCop_(1987)).

> The main weapon used by RoboCop (Peter Weller) is the "Auto 9". This
>   is a Beretta 93R machine pistol which was heavily modified for the
>   film, featuring a longer barrel with an enormous compensator/flash
>   hider shaped like a casket (which apparently made the trademark gun
>   twirl fairly difficult to perform), plastic grips, and a taller rear
>   sight to match the raised front sight. Typically, RoboCop fires this
>   weapon in 3-round burst mode. The fictional stats of the weapon claim
>   it has an implausibly huge 50-round magazine.
>
> Originally it was planned for Robocop to simply carry a Desert Eagle,
>   but Verhoeven felt that the pistol looked too small compared to
>   Robocop's bulky armour, so a special weapon was devised.

[image: Beretta 93R]

Comment: Thank you for introducing the imfdb site. I wasn't aware of its existence, and yet I consider myself a movie-worm.

Comment: Imaginatively I think his arm was mechanical and the rounds were fed through the palm becoming one withe gun..

Comment: "enormous compensator/flash hider"  well something didn't go as planned then.

Comment: The barrel flutes probably inspired design of Medusa Model 47, which is quite interesting piece itself.

Comment: As someone who enjoys SciFi-P&P-RPGs located in the near future (specifically *Shadowrun*) it's nice to see where the authors (likely) took inspiration for weapons designs and stats that would be impractical for regular people but go well with heavily cybernetically modified wielders.